# Using jquery, how to I animate adding a new list item to a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple javascript function that allows me to add an item to a list. Note that I use JQuery...

```
function prependListItem(listName, listItemHTML)
{
    //Shift down list items...
    $("#" + listName + " li:first").slideDown("slow");

    //Add new item to list...
    $(listItemHTML).prependTo("#" + listName)       
}
```

The 'listName' is simply an `<ul>` with some `<li>`'s.

The prepending works fine, but I can't get the slideDown effect to work. I would like the list items to slide down and the new item to then appear on top. Any ideas how to accomplish this? I'm still new to JQuery...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you wanted it to be added and slide down at the same time do this:

```
function prependListItem(listName, listItemHTML){
    $(listItemHTML).hide().prependTo('#' + listName).slideDown('slow');
}
```

To truly do exactly what you described (slide down, *then* fade in),  you would need something like this:

```
function prependListItem(listName, listItemHTML){
    $(listItemHTML)
        .hide()
        .css('opacity',0.0)
        .prependTo('#' + listName)
        .slideDown('slow')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0})
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I assume slideDown makes the item visible again? (un-hides it?)

Comment: Yes, it will animate it in from a hidden state. The important thing is to hide it before prepending it so there is no flicker (appear then disappear).

Comment: @dcneiner: you can skip the nested callback with just `.slideDown('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0})`. The jQuery queues up animations for you by default.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$("<li>new item</li>").hide().prependTo("#" + listName).slideDown("slow");
```

In other words:

- Create the new list item;
- Hide it (so it's not visible when added to the list);
- Add it to the top of the list; then
- Slide it down. The other items will slide down.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/eCpEL/13/

this should help

Using keyframe animation

```
.comefromtop {
    animation: comefromtop 0.5s;
}
.pushdown {
    animation: pushdown 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes comefromtop {
  0%   { opacity:0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
  100% { opacity:1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);   }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pushdown {
  0%   { /*opacity:0;*/ -webkit-transform: translateY(-10%); }
  100% { /*opacity:1;*/ -webkit-transform: translateY(0);   }
}
```

And using a basic javascript

```
function add() {
    var val = $('#input').val();
    var item = $('<li></li>').addClass('comefromtop').attr('id',val).text(val);         $('#Trees').prepend(item).addClass('pushdown');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#Trees').removeClass('pushdown');
    }, 600);
}
$('.add').click(add);
$('#input').on('keypress',function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        add();
    }
});
```

You can achieve godliness