# Animating a changing ranking table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, animation

I have a ranking table which changes every second. I want to animate the table rows smoothly  (not necessarily every second; maybe every 5 seconds).

A quick search revealed [this jQuery plugin](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2011/01/animating-html-ranking-tables-with-javascript/), based on [this animated table sort](http://www.mitya.co.uk/scripts/Table-sort---now-REGEXP-friendly-111). For my purposes, it looks a bit too much like a sports ranking, and the code is outdated and unmaintained.

Are there alternative plugins/libraries to animate changing ranking tables?

Comment: Does it need to be a table? or could it be a set of `<div>`s that look like a table?

Comment: It can be `div`s that look like a table, although a table would be preferential (as I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for styling).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an interesting post on stackoverflow on your same subject:
[Using jquery, how to I animate adding a new list item to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851475/using-jquery-how-to-i-animate-adding-a-new-list-item-to-a-list)

Of course it should be changed a little bit, because maybe you want to add more than one item to the list.

But what you can do is to refresh it every X seconds, and for each of the list item add the item in an animated way.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this link which has a demos for different kind of sorting algorithms.

http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/nearly-sorted-initial-order

However, this not a jQuery plug-in, but I think it can help you.